# problem with drf-spectacular, after 60 urls display 'string' in example value

Tags: swagger, drf-spectacular

so in my swagger after 60 endpoints in box where should be example value data, it just display 'string'. I moved some endpoints to top(in first 60) it worked and show proper example data.

didnt try anything, because dont even know where to move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the swagger version of drf spectacular and it worked.

SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
...
'SWAGGER_UI_DIST':'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@5.11.5'
}

Comment: I've been going through all the code, so in the end it's swagger's fault XD.

Comment: same, ahaha, it was crazy night as soon as I understood what was the problem,  still didn't figure out what even to do with that)) you helped a lot, thanks man

Comment: Here is the github issue tracking the bug: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9652 . It looks like 5.11.8 is the broken version.